# Can I check out svn:externals to the root of the parent directory?

Tags: svn

I have two svn repositories, one each for the iOS and Android versions of a mobile app.  Both versions of the app share an identical SQLite database.  At present each repo has its own copy of the database, which means changes have to be applied twice.

Instead, I would like to add a third repo containing the database and use `svn:externals` to pull a copy into the working folder on checkout for a given version of the app.  I was able to set up externals, but on checkout it creates a subfolder in my working directory and places the external file there.  I want it to pull down the external file without creating a subfolder.

I tried using `.` and `./` as the local path in the externals definition without success.

Is this possible or should I look for another approach?

Edit - Thanks to a good answer from Manojlds I was able to make this work with the database in its own separate repository.  I'm still a little confused because the TortoiseSVN documentation specifically states that:

> The URL for a file external must be in the same repository as the URL
>   that the file external will be inserted into; inter-repository file
>   externals are not supported.

The documentation I'm referring to can be found [here.](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html)  I'm adding a link in case someone comes across this question and is as confused as I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
svn propset svn:externals "^/path/sqlite.db sqlite.db" .
```

(full path above if it is a different repo - why do you need a different repo though? It can be a different folder within the same repo, with iPhone and Android apps being separate projects within the same repo as well. But that is a separate discussion)

Comment: As you said, I was considering moving the two app versions into a single repo as separate projects.  If I were to do that, as well as adding the database in its own folder, would I then use a file external to pull it into each version of the mobile app?

Comment: @Joshua Smith Not sure I got your question, but if you do that, the above command should work for you ( with the relative path indicated by `^`)

Comment: I set up a fake folder structure and was able to make this work as you described.  I should have moved the two mobile apps into a common repo some time ago anyway.  Thank you for the input.

Comment: @Joshua Smith - just so there is no confusion. The same command will work even for external repos provided you give the entire path. you don't have to change to single repo just for this. I was suggesting that as a side.

Comment: Ok, I tried a cross-repo file external earlier and couldn't make it work. The TortoiseSVN documentation specifically says that you cannot do cross-repo file externals. Yet, I went back and tried it with your syntax and it worked perfectly.  I'm not sure what I did wrong the first time.  Either way, thank you very much for your assistance. I'd upvote this several times if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit doesn't make sense, as TortoiseSVN for me does enforce what the documentation says, that you can't external a file in another repo.  I see no way around this, and yet you're claiming that you did it.  Are you sure you didn't just put the three projects into the same repo?

And this isn't a TortoiseSVN issue, as the SVN documentation says the same thing.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html

I would have made this a comment if I had enough reputation.

Comment: I'm impressed that someone commented on this years after I posted it.  I wish I could tell you what I did exactly, but I dropped Subversion like a hot rock when I discovered Git.  Plus, I've long since left the company I was working for at the time.